# Input text box value is not changing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In my .aspx page I have a 'input' html tag, also an asp button.

```
 <input id="Name" type="text" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
 <asp:Button Width="100" type="submit" ID="sendOrder" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitForm" Text="Submit" />
```

On page load, I am filling the value in input tag from code behind, like this:

```
  Name.Value= "X";
```

But now if I change value of this text box from browser, lets say "Y", and click on Submit button, then I get the old value, but not the new one.

```
 protected void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var test= Name.Value; // here I get old value
    }
```

How can I  get the altered value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are only setting the value to "X" when its not a postback:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
   Name.Value= "X";
}
```

Otherwise when clicking the submit button, the `Page_Load()` event will change the value from "Y" back to "X".

Comment: Beat me by 22 seconds my friend, but you get my +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `!IsPostBack` on `Page_Load` shown as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //it's important to use this, otherwise textbox old value overrides again
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Name.Value= "X";
    }
}
```

**Suggestion:**

We can use use `<input></input>` control in asp.net but best practice is to use `<asp:TextBox></asp:TextBox>` control instead.

Here is the sample example:
**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button Width="100" ID="sendOrder" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitForm"
Text="Submit" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //it's important to use this, otherwise textbox old value overrides again
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Name.Text = "Some Value";
    }
}

protected void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = Name.Text; //now get new value here..
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `<input type="text"` **runat="server"** `/>` can't be used in code behind? What is the reason that OP needs to use `<asp:TextBox></asp:TextBox>` instead of `<input></input>` ?

Comment: No, we can use it but if asp.net provides built-in control then why not take an advantage of it?? It's good practice to use it.

Comment: Well, the reader can misinterpret that the problem lies in the control, not in the postback, if you want to suggest put some explanation that it's a suggestion, not just _use x instead of y_

Answer (score 0):

Check for IsPostback in Page_Load so you don't overwrite the values that are submitted!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the else portion, just do this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         //code to execute here only when an action is taken by the user
         //and not affected by PostBack
    }

    //these codes should be affected by PostBack
 }
```